# SQL Server - Dense/Rank not giving desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to give a rank to two columns. Both columns are numeric values and one represents an X coordinate and the other a Y Coordinate.

My select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
 Dense_Rank() over (Partition by X,uniqueid Order by Y ASC) as Y_Rank,
 Dense_Rank() over (Partition by Y,uniqueid Order by X ASC) as X_Rank
      ,[uniqueid]      
  ,[X]
  ,[Y]     
  FROM xxxx.xxxxx
```

The idea being that the statement above would generate an x/y coordinate when concatenated. However my result set is not producing "unique" coordinates or if two rows have the same X but different Y values I'm getting X=1, Y=1 for both rows rather than X=1,Y=1 & X=1,Y=2.

My first question is why is this happening or what am I doing wrong and secondly it appears that rank()/Dense_Rank() doesn't look beyond the decimal, is that true?

I've cast the values to int to remove possible conflicts with floats

```html
+--------+--------+-----+----+--------------------------------------+------------------+
| X_Rank | Y_Rank |  X  | Y  |               uniqueid               | Slot_Side |
+--------+--------+-----+----+--------------------------------------+------------------+
|      1 |      1 |  29 |  4 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fdf27 |                1 |
|      1 |      2 |  29 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fdf27 |                1 |
|      1 |      1 |  52 |  6 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fdf2d |                1 |
|      2 |      1 | 236 |  6 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fdf2d |                1 |
|      1 |      1 |  33 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      1 |      1 |   5 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      2 |      1 |  55 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      2 |      1 |  83 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      3 |      1 | 133 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      3 |      1 | 105 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      4 |      1 | 155 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      4 |      1 | 183 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      5 |      1 | 233 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      5 |      1 | 205 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      6 |      1 | 255 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      6 |      1 | 283 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      7 |      1 | 333 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      7 |      1 | 305 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      8 |      1 | 355 |  3 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      8 |      1 | 383 | 45 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe073 |                0 |
|      1 |      1 |   5 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      2 |      1 |  41 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      3 |      1 |  77 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      4 |      1 | 113 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      5 |      1 | 149 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      6 |      1 | 185 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      7 |      1 | 221 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      8 |      1 | 257 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
|      9 |      1 | 293 |  2 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-fffff27fe074 |                0 |
+--------+--------+-----+----+--------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: If "uniqueid" is truly unique, I don't expect you'd get anything other than 1 for all of your DENSE_RANK() values because you're partitioning by a unique value...

Comment: @ZLK Good point, it's not unique in the sense that you describe. There are multiple rows with the same uniqueid (this value represent the parent for each row). I need that value present as it groups the necessary rows and does the ranking on each uniqueid subset. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't really understand what results you're expecting that are different to the example you've given. All of those X-Y co-ordinates look unique. Or is that what you think it should be producing and it's not doing that?

Comment: I think nobody has answer your question that means you have not well explain enough.you should clearly throw sample data and mention desire output.

Comment: @KumarHarsh  I agree. I've provided sample data that shows the undesired output. If we look at the uniqueid column, specifically the rows ending in 73. I would imagine that the Y values for half of those rows would have a 1 and the other half a 2. Since there y values are either 3 or 45.    If we look at the second two or the third and fourth row you can see the desired outcome. I'm confused why the remaining rows are not providing the desired result?

Comment: @ZLK  Its not that X/Y coordinates are unique or not, but some are wrong, specifically rows where the uniqueid ends in 73. Half of the Y values for uniqueid ending in 73 should be 2. As half of the coordinates have a y with 3 and the other half have 45. The X values are correct for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the flaw in my logic.

Here is the corrected statement:

```
          Select
          Dense_Rank() over (Partition by Y,uniqueid Order by Y) as X_Rank,
          Dense_Rank() over (Partition by uniqueid Order by Y) as Y_Rank
          ,[uniqueid]      
          ,[X]
          ,[Y]     
          FROM xxxx.xxxxx
```

I was tricked by thinking my X_Rank statement was working when really it was a coincidence given the data I was using. The corrected statement gives more weight to the X_Rank by prioritizing or ranking/partitioning it based upon Y. The idea being that I really care about where the Y values change in relation to X, as this indicates the start of a new "Row". My original statement looked at both X and Y equally which returned undesired results. Once I made the relationship for X_Rank I only need to look at Y as it is ordered rather than what Y means in relation to X. Sorry for my poor explanation but at least it works. Thanks for the help regardless!